# Converting UINavigationController to image makes the UINavigationBar translucent

Tags: ios, swift

I want to convert My `UINavigationController` into an image but the `UINavigationBar` becomes translucent. This is the default `UINavigationBar` and I think the blur does not come out very well.

This is the extension I used to make the images.

```
extension UIView {

    func asImage() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, isOpaque, 0.0)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            layer.render(in: context)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            return image
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

and did this.

`navigationController?.view.asImage()`

How can I get the real image?

**Screenshot:** 
[image: Screenshot]

**Converted image:**
[image: Converted Image]

Code: https://github.com/taoshotaro/NavBarImage

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, provide some relevant code you using.

Comment: Thank you for changing the images. I edited and placed some code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that the navigation bar is translucent. If you go to the storyboard, select the navigation bar in your UINavigationController and uncheck the Translucent property in the Attributes inspector the image should be rendered as desired.

Comment: Sorry, gulyashki the example Images were not good. I changed them and I wanted the `UINavigationBar` a little bit translucent like the default one.